# NodeJS res.send not returning variable value

Tags: node.js, express, post

I'm working on a NodeJS/Express program and I'm trying to get a POST request to return data. When I return a direct string, I get the correct response.

```
app.post("/DoStuff", function(req, res, Data) {
  DoStuf.DoStuffFunction(req.body.UserID, function(label) {
    Data = label
    })
    res.send({message: "Stuff"});
  })
```

When I change it to return a variable (which is still a string) it only returns "{}".

```
app.post("/DoStuff", function(req, res, Data) {
  DoStuf.DoStuffFunction(req.body.UserID, function(label) {
    Data = label
    })
    res.send({message: Data});
  })
```

Even when I make Data = "foo" the response is "{}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send from inside of callback function. In your code `res.send` is independent of `DoStuffFunction`'s callback

```
app.post("/DoStuff", function(req, res, Data) {
  DoStuf.DoStuffFunction(req.body.UserID, function(label) {
    Data = label;
    res.send({message: Data});
    })   
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `DoStuffFunction` is async. So just move `res.send(..)` in callback.Something like

```
app.post("/DoStuff", function(req, res, Data) {
  DoStuf.DoStuffFunction(req.body.UserID, function(label) {
    res.send({message: label});
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I change it to return a variable (which is still a string) it only returns "{}".

This is because `DoStuf.DoStuffFunction(){}` is **asynchronous**.

The reason why it works when you use `stuff` as value is because the operation is synchronous. And you have value with you before sending the response.

If you want to send response *only after the DoStuffFunction() completes*, place the `response.send()` within the callback.

```
'use strict';

app.post("/DoStuff", function(req, res, Data) {
  DoStuf.DoStuffFunction(req.body.UserID, function(label) {
    res.send({message: label}); //you can send label's value directly
    });
});
```